# Recursive calling of a method as an argument in python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function in python, but instead of returning an integer type it returns a nonetype. I know there are other questions smiliar to this but not a single solution there worked for me.
Here is the code:

```
class t:
def search(self, globina, board):
    board.legals = board.legal()
    bestMove = 0
    if(globina == 0):
        return board.evaluation()
    elif board.turn == False:
        bestMove = -9999
        for i in range(0, len(board.legals)):
            board.move(board.legals[i])
            board.display()
            bestMove = max(bestMove, self.search(globina-1, board))
            board.undo()
        return bestMove

    else:
        bestMove = 9999
        for i in range(0, len(board.legals)):
            board.move(board.legals[i])
            board.display()
            bestMove = min(bestMove, self.search(globina-1, board))
            board.undo()
        return bestMove
z = t()
z.search(globina, board)
```

Comment: This code won't even run `IndentationError`

Comment: if globina != 0  it's very likely that you don't return anything

Comment: @AmitTripathi I think he didn't produce it correctly in the question. Maybe he did do it properly on his editor since he got some output.

Comment: @AakashVerma Yes, I think so. But if someone is asking a question SO and expecting others to give their time and help, formatting and readable English is least one can expect.

Comment: @AmitTripathi Look, he's a newbie. Plus I never said that it is convenient for people to read; I said it would have run!

Comment: I edited the code, i didn't notice that i didn't even post the whole thing, sorry.

Comment: @Annadox: I don't see any way that this code could return `None`, since all of its branches have `return` statements. The only possibility I could imagine is that `board.evaluation()` returns `None` in some situation, but I'd expect that to cause an exception later (since `max(whatever, None)` won't work). Oh, I guess that's a question: Which version of Python are you using? Python 2 does actually allow `None` to be compared to numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the help, board.evaluation() was returning none.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive method (as it appears in edited question) is doing the right thing, since it uses `return` in all of its cases.

That means that the `None` value must not be due to the recursive function itself, but rather it's a value being returned in the base case somewhere. For your function, that means `board.evaluation()` returns `None` at least some of the time.

In Python 3, I'd expect that to cause an exception in any of the recursive cases, as `min` and `max` will choke on a `None` value (since `None` isn't comparable to anything, including itself). In Python 2 however, all objects are comparable, though there may not be any particular meaning to comparisons between unlike types. The default behavior is to compare class names alphabetically (so all `int` and `float` instances are less than all `str` instances, which are less than all `tuple`s), though if I recall correctly, `None` compares as less than all other values.